# Scroll wheel causes browsers + Windows explorer to go back

Tags: windows, virtualbox, browser, scroll-wheel

I use Windows 7 on a VirtualBox VM on a Mac. Lately, when I'm using any browser (IE9, Chrome or FireFox or even Windows Explorer), use of the scroll wheel followed by any movement of the mouse cursor causes the browser to go back. *Very* annoying.

This happens when I use the scroll wheel on a USB connected mouse (brand/model unknown, since I don't have it in front of me as I write this) or when I use two-finger scrolling on the trackpad when no mouse is connected.

When I connect from my VM to a remote Windows box (Windows Server 2008), I experience the same problem.

I have tried rebooting the VM to no avail.

I am not sure when the problem started exactly. It may or may not have been after I connected the USB mouse for the first time, but trying to unplug it and then rebooting didn't help.

I have tried to google for a solution, but all I've found are people who accidentally pressed the shift key while scrolling, which will cause the browser to go backward or forward in the browser history. This however is *not* the problem I'm having. To be clear, in my case the browser only goes back when I move the mouse *after* I've used the scroll wheel.

I'm at my wits end :(

Comment: Does it work as expected if you boot Windows in Safe Mode?

Comment: No, the problem persists even when I boot in Safe Mode.

Comment: Tried disabling graphics hardware acceleration?